# how can I download more than one podcast in iTunes but not all of them to my computer?

Tags: itunes

once the podcasts are on my computer, I can select to put only the ten most recent unlistened to synch to my iphone, but what if I want to only download the ten most recent, -- the question is, how do I do less than "get all" but more than selecting a single one or two episodes of a particular podcast?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag files from iTunes onto the iPhone section, on the left where it says your phone name. If you drag any file from your library onto that part of the screen it will sync it your iPhone, same applies to podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to right click on the podcast and choose Show All Available, then click Get on the 10 episodes you want.